# Including protocol function in tapGesture action selector - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, selector, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a class (FilterBar.swift) and a viewcontroller. the viewcontroller calls the class to populate a scrollView object with list of images and each image has a tapGestureRecognizer added to it as follows:

```
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
                        target: imgView, action: Selector("filterClicked:"));
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
        tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
        imgView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);
```

and i have a function also in FilterBar as follows:

```
    @objc func filterClicked(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print(sender.view?.superview?.description)
    print("sent from view: \(sender.view!.tag)");
}
```

when i attempt to click on the image i get the following error:

```
2016-03-16 02:06:45.800 ImageFilter[71811:6885004] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView delegate.filterClicked:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc07951f010'
```

So i thought maybe i need a protocol, so i created a protocol in FilterBar as follows:

```
protocol FilterClickedDelegate {
    func filterClicked(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer);
}

let delegate:FilterClickedDelegate?

(adjusted this line) let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
             target: imgView, action: Selector("delegate.filterClicked:"));
```

i added that protocol to the viewcontroller class, and i also added the function the protocol needs but i still get the same error. So first question: Am i right to use a protocol in this senario since this is running on viewcontroller?

second question: what am i doing wrong in the selector? is there a specific way to mention a protocol function in the selector?

Comment: Which line does it crash?

Comment: not on any line just when i click the image it crashes

Comment: try deleting @objc

Comment: same thing no change

Comment: `target: imgView` change this to - `target: self, action...`

Comment: Target needs to be the delegate. Selector needs to be the delegate function you'd like the recognizer to call

Comment: @beyowulf how do i set the delegate function in action? do i do Selector("delegate.filterClicked:")

Comment: You can say `let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
             target: self.delegate, action: "filterClicked:")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, in the target section when initializing the UITapGestureRecognizer you need to use the viewcontroller which is actually the delegate of the delegator. so:

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureController(target: vc, action:"filterClicked:");
```

Thanks all, and hope this will help others stuck on the same issue!

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The last line of your post code:

```
(adjusted this line) let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
             target: imgView, action: Selector("delegate.filterClicked:"));
```

I think should be:

```
(adjusted this line) let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
         target: delegate, action: Selector("filterClicked:"));
```

I think it will work.
But I don't suggest doing in this way, it's some kind strange. What I usually do is:

```
(adjusted this line) let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(
         target: self, action: Selector("filterClicked:"));
```

And If I really need to inform `delegate` to do something, I will call `delegate` to do it in the `filterClicked:`. Just like:

In the ViewController:

```
fun filterClicked() {
// delegate to do something
delegate.xxx()
}
```

Comment: i cant use target: delegate because it says its not AnyObject? and i tried it your way that didnt fire at all. I have to use a delegate because im firing it from another class. so if i did it your way using self that self is referring to the class not the viewcontroller where i am actually clicking on the image.